# Cannot run several CMDs in Dockerfile, last one gets ignored

Tags: docker, unix, nginx, dockerfile

I have the following legacy Dockerfile which runs fine:

```
FROM some/service:base

WORKDIR /myapp


COPY frontend/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site
COPY frontend/build dist
COPY . .

CMD service nginx start && cd /myapp/server1 && exec python3 app.py
```

Now I need to update it slightly and make it start one more server, like:

```
...
CMD service nginx start && cd /myapp/server1 && exec python3 app.py && cd /myapp/server2 && exec npm start server.js
```

This approach fails (i.e. I don't see my server.js being running). I am lost at debugging this on my own. Any help will be appreciated.
Is there a way to do this without adding several Docker layers? I would like to keep it simple if possible.

Comment: The `/myapp/` is a relative link or really mounted at `/` ?

Comment: @Inian it is a working dir being set for `CMD`.

Comment: Even though it sounds like more moving pieces, it is probably simpler to set up multiple containers, possibly using Docker Compose to connect them together.  That would let you have a straightforward `CMD exec python3 app.py` in each container, and let you restart the components independently when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is (at least) due to using `exec` in your commands.

The `exec` command **replaces** the current process with the command it receives as argument, therefore, interrupting your `&&` command chain.

Example of how it fails:

```
FROM alpine
CMD echo 1 && exec echo 2 && echo 3
```

Build and run this Dockerfile, and you will only see `1` and `2` as output, but not `3`.

Remove the `exec`s from your command, and it should be fine.

Further reference:

```
$ exec --help
exec: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] 
    Replace the shell with the given command.

    Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
```

As an additional tip, I would consider putting all these commands inside an `entrypoint.sh` script, and running **it** in the `CMD` instead of chaining multiple commands using `&&`.

Comment: Thank you @DannyB. One more question, if I leave it this way `CMD service nginx start && cd /myapp/server1 && python3 app.py && cd /myapp/server2 && npm start server.js` what will I benefit from it? (Please notice, I removed `exec` here).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question "what will I benefit from it?" - benefit compared to what?